# Removing duplication (with Applicative ((->) t), perhaps?)

Tags: haskell, applicative

I was playing around with a simple function for someone else's Stack Overflow question, and wrote the expression:

```
f a x ++ f a y
```

Obviously this is the best way to write that expression in real life, given I have all those variables in scope anyway, but I saw the duplication of `f a`, and thought "Hey, maybe you can remove that with the Applicative instance for functions". I wound up with:

```
liftA2 (++) (flip f x) (flip f y) a
```

which is just awful. Is there some nicer way to remove this duplication?Obviously I could also remove the duplication by binding `f a` to something in a `where` clause, but this was intended as an exercise in using built-in functions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do

```
((++) `on` f a) x y
```

That doesn't use `Applicative`, though (sorry).

Comment: I like this answer, though! I guess I wasn't really looking for Applicative answers specifically, so much as ways to use the standard library to remove the duplication.

Answer (score 21):

> [...] maybe you can remove that with the Applicative instance for functions.

Do you have to use the `Applicative` instance of `((->) t)`? If you just want to get rid of the duplicated `f a`, why not use the list monad, instead?

```hs
[x, y] >>= f a
```

or, equivalently,

```hs
f a =<< [x, y]
```

Example:

```hs
λ> let f :: Int -> Int -> [Int]; f a x = [a .. x]

λ> f 1 2 ++ f 1 3
[1,2,1,2,3]

λ> [2, 3] >>= f 1
[1,2,1,2,3]

λ> f 1 =<< [2, 3]
[1,2,1,2,3]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `=<<` is the same as `concatMap` in this situation, so if you want to think about this in terms of list manipulations instead of monads, that's the function to use.

Comment: @cool_me5000 Sure, but I wanted to emphasize the monadic aspect of the operation.

Answer (score 15):

Bikeshedding is fun! Another option would be to use the `Monoid` instance for functions:

```
(($x) <> ($y)) (f a)
```

Comment: I don't understand this one. Isn't `mappend` composition, for functions? And what happened to the `++`?

Comment: @amalloy For functions, `mappend` is pointwise appending: `mappend f g x = mappend (f x) (g x)`. The `(++)` disappears because it is the `mappend` that happens at each point.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question hinted at a solution using Applicative (although other answers are more elegant)...

```
((++) <$> ($ x) <*> ($ y)) (f a)
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of some parentheses, you can write: `(++) <$> ($ x) <*> ($ y) $ f a`.

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not sure if he's right or not, but I've decided to road-test Gabriel Gonzalez's advice on making Haskell code more readable to non-Haskellers: http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/09/how-to-make-your-haskell-code-more.html.  Avoiding `($)` is his top recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the link `:)`

Comment: @frasertweedale I personally find the version with `$` much more readable, parenthesis are annoying as you have to match them up with each other, and so as you get more and more of them it becomes progressively more of a pain in the ass to decipher the order of operations. Whereas `$` doesn't need to be matched with anything. It really doesn't take long to figure out how `$` works and I consider that to be a perfectly acceptable small barrier to reading Haskell code.